# Error Handling For ResposeWriter / Write

Tags: go, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using osin, [Go Lang oAuth Server](http://github.com/RangelReale/osin) to try and build a oAuth sever.

So I have used, or i am trying to use the complete example given, to give me a good place to start playing with the code to see what I can do.

However, I have a lot of errors with the file. Now most seem to be about error checking and i have seem to fix them (I am using Visual Code, which as very good Go Lang support). However, no matter what I try I cant seem to fix the error handling for `w.Write`,

```
http.HandleFunc("/appauth/code", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm() //*1 
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    code := r.Form.Get("code")

    w.Write([]byte("<html><body>")) *2
```

*1 - This was also missing an error and found my understanding this is how that is meant to be dealt with, please tell me if I am wrong?

*2 - With this I am getting, a errors unhandled call within Visual Code, and no matter how I try to deal with it, it will not work?

This is what I have tried,

```
err := w.Write([]byte("<html><body>"))

w.Write([]byte("<html><body>") (int, error) ) <- the Write seems to return an int and error?
```

So I am not sure how to deal with this type of error?

Comment: No reason to call `log.Panic` just because someone sent you an invalid form. In most cases you would use [http.Error](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error) to return a proper error code to the client and not crash your server.

Comment: I was not sure what type of error to use and most of my research into go lang as been using log.Panic, I know where are a lot of different error types, I look into that one. Many thanks

Comment: [ResponseWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter)'s `Write` returns two values (note that Go allows multiple return values), an `int` indicating the number of bytes writen and an `error` if one occured. As already stated in @Sridhar's answer, you can discard return values by using the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier); scroll down a bit from [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) to see the relevant explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discard the int if you don't need it:

```
_, err := w.Write([]byte("<html><body>"))
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. Side note, in this file, there are lots of w.Write, so do I have to do that for all of them? or is there a better way of building / concatenating the data?

Comment: write returns two values, so yes. If you don't mind a suggestion - take some time to read through [effective go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) specifically [multiple returns](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#multiple-returns)